# Big gap between elements in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to design my website and I got this big white gap between my navigation bar and image. Where have I done wrong here?

Also side note: Does anyone know how I can "box" my entire page to let there be empty white spaces on the sides?

HTML:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Design</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box">
                <div id="header">
                    <br />
                    <div style="margin-left: 1250px;">
                        <input id="sweBtn" type="button" value="SVENSKA" />
                        <input id="engBtn" type="button" value="ENGLISH" />
                        <input id="searchTxt" type="text" />
                        <input id="searchBtn" type="button" value="SÖK" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-left" id="imgTitle">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img id="imgHeader" src="~/img/Header.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="navBar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
<link href="~/Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }

#header {
    background-color: #503F31;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
}

#sweBtn {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: grey;
}

#engBtn {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: gold;
}

#searchTxt {
    background-color: grey;
    border-color: grey;
}

#searchBtn {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: gold;
}

#imgTitle {
    position: absolute;
}

#imgHeader {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 3400px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: -250px;
}
```

Doesnt matter what elements I use, it still a big gap. Help please

Comment: `margin-left: 1250px;` is the culprit. It will leave huge space of 1250px from left of screen

Comment: No, I deleted it. Its still the same, and my menu items is not where they are supposed to be anymore.

Comment: jsfiddle could be helpful. please open one to show us what exactly is happening with your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/prvej1vz/

See that big gap?`

Comment: You sure you added all the css and there's no other css in your fiddle?